# How to load level 1 when the cutscene ends?

Tags: unity, c#, loading, cutscene

I use timeline for creating an opening cutscene and I want to load the first level after the cutscene ends. So, I decided to use timeline signals. I created a signal emitter at the end of the cutscene and added `LoadGamePlay` script to the signal receiver component. The problem is that the function doesn't show up in the dropdown menu. I can just select "string name" and write the scene name in the inspector. But this doesn't help so level 1 cannot be loaded. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
public class LoadGamePlay : MonoBehaviour
{
   public string myScene = "";

   public void LoadLevel()
   {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(myScene);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you drag a script file into where it says LoadGamePlay, rather than a GameObject with an instance of the LoadGamePlay component attached to it? You won't be able to reference any instance methods (methods without `static` in their declaration) unless you have a reference to an instance of the component, not the script that defines the class.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the root of the problem. Thank you! I'll write this as an answer.

Comment: @DMGregory I just have a quick question since it is related to this one. The level 1 scene loads very quickly (less than a second). So I wanted to ask do I need to add a loading screen in between? For sure I'll add more content to the first level so this way it might take longer but even in that situation, I think a loading screen (or a loading bar) would be pointless.

Comment: It sounds like you've reasoned your way to your preferred answer there.

Comment: Yes, my preferred answer is to not have a loading screen in there but wasn't sure so that was why I asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem, I followed these steps:

1. Created an empty obejct.
2. Attached `LoadGamePlay` script to it as a component.
3. Wrote the name of the scene I wanted to load. In this case, it was "Level 1".
4. Dragged the game object into Signal Receiver in the inspector.
5. In the drop down menu, selected `LoadGamePlay` and then `LoadLevel()`.

***Note:** You can also drag the object into Signal Emitter's inspector*
field.

[image]